# gradle taking too long too build in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-14.04

I recently installed android studio in Ubuntu 14.04 and wish to continue working on the android apps i've been working on in windows. But when I try to open some of the projects, it's taking forever to build. I've waited for close to an hour but it still doesn't seem to compile and build.
Please any help? or suggestions as to what might be the cause. 
Your help will be much appreciated.

This is what my build.gradle looks like

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.


buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {


 jcenter()


 }

}
```

Comment: Is anything showing in the Gradle console? Is the cpu busy or is something perhaps deadlocked?

Comment: Does your  project depends on multiple libraries? Also check system configuration. see task manager if cpu usage is nearby 100%.

Comment: @Tauqir Nothing shows on the gradle console, and i don't think my cpu is busy, or anything is deadlocked, because it opens other project without problems. I don't know how to check if my project depends on multiple libraries. any help? Thanks

Comment: @user3229080, paste your build.gradle

Comment: Here is it// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: It might be downloading tons of libraries. Are you on a fast network?

Comment: for the first run, it needs to download the gradle (and other libraries)  and this might take some time depending upon the speed of your connection , check your gradle wrapper folder to see what is being downloaded

Comment: @Pablo i think you guys are right. It just finished building now. but does it need to always download this for every project?

Comment: @PruthviRaj I checked the gradle wrapper folder but didn't see much. the jar file there is not up to a MB. and the whole project folder weighs 15MB only

Comment: I believe Gradle does not store the downloaded dependencies in the project folder. Look for a folder called .gradle in your home directory's root and you'll probably find them.

Comment: you are right @Pablo, I found them there. Thank u guys very much

Answer (score 0):

some project requires certain support libraries/jar file to be downloaded and should be installed.You have to untick the offline mode in the project properties